# PHP Correct use of File_Exists

Tags: php

I have a form to upload text and an image to a server/database, every condition works except from my use of `file_exists`.

What is wrong with this;

```
if(isset($_FILES["tipimage"]) && $_FILES["tipimage"]["error"] == 0){
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        $filename = $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["tipimage"]["type"];
        $targetDir = "uploads/";
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $filename;

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {
            $error .= "Invalid File Format<br>";
          } 
        }

        if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"])){
          $error .= "File" . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"] . " already exists.<br>";
        }

          else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tipimage"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            $successmsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image - " . $filename . " Uploaded Successfully!</div>";
          }


      if($error) {
        $dangererror = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
        $dangererror .= $error;
        $dangererror .= "</div>";
      }
```

Comment: where do you move the uploaded file to 'uploads/'?

Comment: `upload/` != `uploads/ `.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes. It's stored in a variable

Comment: Provide __full path__ to file for `file_exists`

Comment: Typo. @tkausl was correct. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a simple typo.

My variable was set to 'uploads'

```
$targetDir = "uploads/";
```

Which is the correct path, in the if statement I wrote 'upload'

```
if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"])){
          $error .= "File" . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"] . " already exists.<br>";
        }
```